# asterisk get credit card info

Tags: asterisk, telephony

I`m trying to build a script that will capture the credit card info like card number,cvc and expiration date using asterisk 11.x and asterisk-java library for AMI/AGI integration.

Right now I am able to build a script that will acquire that info if it is called via dialplan but i have a different scenario:
1. A call enters a queue.
2. An agent from the specific queue answer the call
3. The caller wants to input the card details
4. After the caller has entered the card details is redirected back to agent to continue the call.

My specific problem is related to step 3 as I do not know how to route the caller to my AGI and then back to the same agent. (eventually the agents has to be still involved in (some) call to guarantee that when the caller returns from agi it is still available)
Any idea how can I achieve that ? I know that this is a common practice so I think that there has to be a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the call is delivered to the agent, use a macro to set a custom channel variable with the agent ID or extension in it.

Then, when your credit-card authentication function is done, read the variable and use an AGI command to transfer the call back to the agent.

**Further Reading**

- http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variables
- http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Example:+Transfer

***Note*** *if this solution solves your problem, please 'accept' it to make it easier for others with the same issue to find it.  thanks!*

Comment: Just to make sure that i understand : A call enters the queue, the call is answered by an agent. Agent transfers call to the credit card process extension. While the customer is entering cc details the agent is not on call anymore(he/she can event answer other calls- which is not ok ). After the customer enters the credit card details my agi should call the same agent back. If so this will generate 2 calls in my CDR and statistics and i somehow want to avoid that...

Comment: So deliver the queued customer call into a conference call with the agent, and have the credit-card app join and leave the conference.

Comment: I'll try and come back with feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are no any common practice for business process like you have. That depend of you and your client only.

You can use features conf or transfer. Can transfer to special extension or to conference room.

No way say what suite you better.

For sure you need understand how asterisk work before write any AGI/AMI or dialplan application. I can recommend ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony" book as start point.

Comment: I have some experience with asterisk (dialplan, realtime,ami,agi). It is true that I have used features.conf only for blind/attended transfers and barely touch the meetme subject.  Regarding the 1st solution with transfer, if I transfer the call to any extension I will loose the agent on the other part of the line. I guess that meetme would be a solution but I do not know how to achieve this from a design flow perspective.

Comment: Transfer command transfer called party to next one extension. You just need re-read all docs. For metmee variant google "asterisk n-way calling"